# use geom_line or geom_path to connect points with different categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the movements of animals based on a specific state (categorical variable: detType).  However, neither geom_line nor geom_path connects the points between different states.

E.g.

```
ggplot(data = filter(df, ID == 8), #just plotting 1 individual for example
       aes(recvLon, recvLat)) +
  geom_path(aes(colour=detType)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=detType))
```

[image: example plot]

I would like a blue postDep line connecting the red and uppermost blue points.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if I add dplyr::lead() to the geom_path this helps to select the correct colour for the line.

E.g. from above

```
ggplot(data = filter(df, ID == 8),
       aes(recvLon, recvLat)) +
  geom_path(aes(colour=dplyr::lead(detType))) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=detType))
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument `aes(colour=detType)` in `geom_path` means that there are different lines for the different levels of `detType`. Just remove the argument and use `geom_path()` instead to draw a single line connecting all points.

Comment: Thanks @Sven Hohenstein, but I'd still like the line to be different colours.  Although this example only has two states, for some animals I have several different states, so I need to colour those.

Comment: If the points that are connected by a line have different colours, what is the desired colour of the line?

Comment: The colour of the later of the two points.  So for the example above, the connecting line would be blue.